# Insert variable in a string quoteed with ` character

Tags: javascript

I try to insert variable in a string who will be added in a row of a table

var newLetter = "hello";

```
var row = `
    <tr>
      <td  data-id="+newLetter+">"+newLetter+"</td>
      <td> <input class="" type="checkbox" name="comp"> </td>
      <td> <input class="" type="checkbox" name="flex"> </td>
      <td> <input class="" type="checkbox" name="abs"> </td>
    </tr>
    `;

document.getElementById("class1").insertRow(-1).innerHTML = row;
```

I create a basic example at http://jsfiddle.net/8kndew35/

Seem like variable **value** is not inserted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```
var row = `
<tr>
  <td  data-id="${newLetter}">${newLetter}</td>
  <td> <input class="" type="checkbox" name="comp"> </td>
  <td> <input class="" type="checkbox" name="flex"> </td>
  <td> <input class="" type="checkbox" name="abs"> </td>
</tr>
`;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use this format:

```js
var row = `
    <tr>
      <td  data-id="${newLetter}">${newLetter}</td>
      <td> <input class="" type="checkbox" name="comp"> </td>
      <td> <input class="" type="checkbox" name="flex"> </td>
      <td> <input class="" type="checkbox" name="abs"> </td>
    </tr>
    `;
```

See [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).